# which pip package creates psycopg2 dependency?

Tags: python, django, pip

This is what i mean, i am trying to install all the packages in my requirements.txt (django/python), i did not specify some packages like asgiref, psycopg2, urllib etc, but it just starts downloading or installing them too, then i thought: there must be some packages that are also downloading these other ***asgiref, psycopg2, urllib etc*** as dependencies.

Does anyone know what package that might be from this lists?

requirements.txt

```
boto3==1.20.26
botocore==1.23.54
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.7
django-auto-logout==0.5.0
django-ckeditor==6.0.0
django-crispy-forms==1.12.0
django-dotenv==1.4.2
django-environ==0.9.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-jazzmin==2.4.8
django-plaintext-password==0.1.0
django-static-fontawesome==5.14.0.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
Pillow==9.1.0
psycopg2-binary
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `pip show package_name` in the terminal to show the details as 'Requires' and 'Required-by'.

For more details:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_show/